# Better for loop performance to check radiobuttons

Tags: c#, for-loop, radio-button

I have 512 separate `radio buttons` and each of them is related with a `bool` to display.

I made a function with `for loop` but it uses lots of CPU. Is there a better way to do this?

```
for (int k = 0; k < NUMWORDS_FOR_PLCTOHMI_BOOLS * 16; k++)
{
    string sRadioButtonName = "radioButton_PLCtoHMI_Bool" + k.ToString();
    RadioButton r = Controls.Find(sRadioButtonName, true)[0] as RadioButton;
    r.Checked = KepwarearrWordtoBools_PLCtoHMI[k];
}
```

Comment: you can use foreach loop. Is this a winform or WPF??

Comment: I think Controls.find uses lots of CPU. What do you think?

Answer (score 1):

You could retrieve all radiobuttons first, and then iterate them afterwards in memory like this:

```
var radioButtons = this.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>();

for (int k = 0; k < NUMWORDS_FOR_PLCTOHMI_BOOLS * 16; k++)
{
    string sRadioButtonName = "radioButton_PLCtoHMI_Bool" + k.ToString();
    RadioButton r = radioButtons.Single(x => x.Name == sRadioButtonName);
    r.Checked = KepwarearrWordtoBools_PLCtoHMI[k];
}
```

This should be more efficient.

Comment: This assumes that all radiobutton are directly contained in the this container. If they are dispersed in different containers this will not work

Answer (score 1):

An example how to do it if the Controls were in a List:

```
List<RadioButton> radioButtons = new List<RadioButton>(); 
//Fill the List with the controls

for (int k = 0; k < radioButtons.Count; k++)
{
   radioButtons[k].Checked = KepwarearrWordtoBools_PLCtoHMI[k];
}
```

The only thing left is to fill the `List`.

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to create a Dictionary, as its access time to find an item is very fast.

When you create your buttons :

```
private Dictionary<String, RadioButton> buttons = new Dictionary<String, RadioButton>();

//Wherever you create those buttons
buttons.Add("radiobutton_PLCtoHMI_Bool" + k.toString());

//When you want to get them
for (int k = 0; k < NUMWORDS_FOR_PLCTOHMI_BOOLS * 16; k++)
{
    string sRadioButtonName = "radioButton_PLCtoHMI_Bool" + k.ToString();
    //You find it faster than with Controls.Find()
    RadioButton r = buttons(sRadioButtonName);
    r.Checked = KepwarearrWordtoBools_PLCtoHMI[k];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var rb in this.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>())
{
   var k = rb.Name.Substring(25); // because "radioButton_PLCtoHMI_Bool" has 25 characters
   int i;
   if(int.TryParse(k, out i)) //if k is an integer 
      rb.Checked = KepwarearrWordtoBools_PLCtoHMI[i];
}
```

Comment: You could provide some more context on why you have chosen this code. What the benefits are over the code provided by @tebdilikyafet

Answer (score 0):

I suggest *logic reversing*: looping over `RadioButton`s we detect if each `ReadioButton` should be checked or not:

```
  // providing that all the radio buttons are on the form;
  // if they are on, say, myPanel, put myPanel instead of "this"
  var rButtons = this
    .Controls
    .OfType<RadioButton>()
    .Where(item => item.Name.StartsWith("radioButton_PLCtoHMI_Bool"));

  foreach (var rb in rButtons) {
    int index;

    if (int.TryParse(rb.Name.SubString("radioButton_PLCtoHMI_Bool".Length), out index))
      if (index >= 0 && index < KepwarearrWordtoBools_PLCtoHMI.Length)
        rb.Checked = KepwarearrWordtoBools_PLCtoHMI[index];
  }
```